# Get all external source paths that a JAR uses

Tags: java, jar, decompiling

I have a problem with finding all the external libraries that a `.jar` file uses. My `.jar` file is very big, and manually decompiling it and going through every class, checking all the used paths is impossible. I wonder if there is a way or a tool that would go through a .jar file, and list all the external paths/links to classes that are not in the .jar file?

P.S: I'm not asking "what is the best tool to do so?", I just need to know how to get all the external paths a `.jar` file uses, without manually decompiling it.

Comment: What's the exact problem you are trying to solve? Perhaps a better alternative to finding all external classes could be suggested.

Comment: @Rajeev lol, My main goal is to deobfuscate a modded minecraft client by obfuscating it with proguard. right now, all the classes/variables/methods are named with 20 random letters/numbers, and i'm just trying to make them named A,b,c etc. But to do so, I need to know all it's dependencies :D

Comment: @Rajeev some classes are named with over 260 characters, so I can't decompile, and export them to an eclipse project, because the file path limitation in Windows is 260 characters max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

1. Extract the jar contents
2. Do a directory search for `*.class` piped to a text file.
3. Filter out inner and anonymous classes. (Class files names with `$`)
4. Write a small program that will simply loop through your list and load the class definition (`Class.forName()` should be enough)
5. Run the jar with option `-verbose:class` piped to a text file
6. Once your program is completed, you will have a full list of classes loaded from respective jars in the piped file
7. Filter out rt.jar contents for a more cleaner list

I'm not sure if `-verbose:class` works with obfustcated code, logically I think it should be fine.